# I need the value of the key in this nested json using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "2407": {
                "gmail": "sus@gmail.com",
                "name": "Shaurya",
                "address": "19B/11 Kamla Nehru Road Civillines Prayagraj",
                "phn": "9161461745",
                "balance":0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to read this json and change the balance key to 100

I tried using :

```
with open(filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print(data["users"]["2407"]["balance"])
```

But its not working

Comment: Can you be more precise than "its not working"?

Comment: i think correct way would be `data["users"][0]["2407"]["balance"]` but as Scott said, cannot tell what exactly isnt working for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import json

with open("temp.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print(data)
        data["users"][0]["2407"]["balance"] = 100
        print(data)
```

Here. You forgot that users is an array